# Summarize Everything except These Value

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

Goal:
Summarize the value of "Reseller Freight Cost" and "Discount Amount" into separated cell with total value in the table.

Problem:
Everything should be included for total selection of a value except "Road" and "Touring" from the "Product Line" column. How should I do it?

[image]

```sql
SELECT
   NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Discount Amount],
   [Measures].[Reseller Freight Cost] } 
   ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY { ([Product].[Category].[Category].ALLMEMBERS * [Product].[Product Line].[Product Line].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,
   MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME 
   ON ROWS 
FROM
   [Adventure Works] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE,
   BACK_COLOR,
   FORE_COLOR,
   FORMATTED_VALUE,
   FORMAT_STRING,
   FONT_NAME,
   FONT_SIZE,
   FONT_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use set exceptions - your query amended below: ( double check as I don't have AW):
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Discount Amount], [Measures].[Reseller Freight Cost] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY

{ ([Product].[Category].[Category].ALLMEMBERS)}
* Except([Product].[Product Line].[Product Line].ALLMEMBERS ,
{[Product].[Product Line].[Product Line].[Road],
[Product].[Product Line].[Product Line].[Touring]})

DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [Adventure Works]

CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS

Answer (score 0):

Also , you can simply add the dataset filtering or tablix filtering with (NOT IN ) .

Answer (score 0):

Also - Your question is not quiet clear to me , the solution it may also be like below:

```
            with 
            member measures.total as 

            iif([Product].[Product Line].currentmember.name = "road" or 
            [Product].[Product Line].currentmember.name = "Touring"
             ,0, [Measures].[Discount Amount]+[Measures].[Reseller Freight Cost])

            SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Discount Amount], [Measures].[Reseller Freight Cost],measures.total  } 
            ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Product].[Category].[Category].ALLMEMBERS * [Product].[Product Line].[Product Line].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [Adventure Works] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```